# Запятая перед И: "Мальчик шел быстро, уверенно(,) и с каждым его шагом..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед союзом И. "Мальчик шел быстро, уверенно, и с каждым его шагом таинственный город становился все ближе, явственнее". Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, нужна. Союз "и" присоединяет вторую часть сложносочиненного предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!